# Yii Editable column not working on ajax call when filling empty grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, yii-extensions

I'm trying to edit column in CGridview using X-editable extension. It works fine when data is preloaded. But it does not work when empty grid is filled with data on Ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '".$this->createUrl('baseContact/upload')."',
    data: data, 
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
       $.fn.yiiGridView.update('BCImported-grid');  //updating grid here                           
    }
      });
```

[image]

Can anyone please give me the solution ?